# shift cipher using lists instead of string

Tags: scheme

I would like to program a Shift or Caesar cipher in Scheme, but not using strings. I would like to use a list instead:

```
(define message '(T H E F O X))
(define k 4)
(define A(char->integer #\A))
(define Z(char->integer #\Z))

(define (cipher message)
  (if (empty? message)
      '()
      (begin
        (display ((+ (char->integer (car message)) k))->char)
        (cipher (cdr message))
        )
      ))

(define (helper)
  (cipher message))
```

I know that is missing the part in which I should use modulo and compare with the limits of A and Z, but the question that I have is how to convert (car message) into a char and then into an integer so I can add the value of k; and then convert it back from integer to char to display its value.

I have found solutions based on strings and map, but how to do it only using a list and with conversions like the above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it be acceptable to convert your list to a string, use the cipher routines that work with strings, and then convert it back to a list when done?

Comment: thanks, as long as I can use recursion on the string to get the chacacters

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding is that you want to work on symbols.

Let's start with the prologue:

```
(define A (char->integer #\A))
(define Z (char->integer #\Z))
(define MOD (+ Z (- A) 1)) ; 26, used for modulo
```

`MOD` has been added since we need to  take the result of the shift `modulo` 26. Now we need procedures to convert from symbol to integer and back:

```
(define (symbol->integer s)
  (char->integer (car (string->list (symbol->string s)))))

(define (integer->symbol i)
  (string->symbol (list->string (list (integer->char i)))))
```

testing:

```
> (symbol->integer 'A)
65
> (integer->symbol 65)
'A
```

and finally the `cipher` procedure. I prefer to have `k` as a parameter:

```
(define (cipher message k)
  (if (empty? message)
      '()
      (cons (integer->symbol (+ A (modulo (+ k (- (symbol->integer (car message)) A)) MOD)))
            (cipher (cdr message) k))))
```

Testing:

```
> (cipher '(T H E F O X) 4)
'(X L I J S B)
```

Comment: exactly @ScottHunter, I would like to keep it like a list

Comment: A list of chars or symbols?

Comment: OK, I've changed to a list of symbols. Hope this helps.

Comment: `(list-ref x 0)` → `(car x)`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Definitely. Thanks, I'll change that monstrosity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic version that allows lists, symbols, strings, and chars. Note that I did not write loops manually (since doing so is painful for me, when `map` is so readily available); you are welcome to do that yourself.

This version uses [SRFI 13](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.html) (for `string-map`) and [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) (for `cut`). (If you are writing the loops manually, and expanding the `cut` by hand, then you will be able to use this in plain Scheme.)

```
(require srfi/13 srfi/26)   ;; for Racket

(define (caesar x shift)
  (cond ((char? x) (caesar-char x shift))
        ((string? x) (caesar-string x shift))
        ((symbol? x) (caesar-symbol x shift))
        ((list? x) (caesar-list x shift))
        (else (error "Unknown type" x))))

(define (caesar-char ch shift)
  (if (char-alphabetic? ch)
      (let* ((ord (char->integer ch))
             (lower (modulo ord 32))
             (upper (- ord lower)))
        (integer->char (+ upper (modulo (+ lower shift) 26))))
      ch))

(define (caesar-string str shift)
  (string-map (cut caesar-char <> shift) str))

(define (caesar-symbol sym shift)
  (string->symbol (caesar-string (symbol->string sym) shift)))

(define (caesar-list lst shift)
  (map (cut caesar <> shift) lst))
```

Example:

```
> (caesar '(T H E F O X) 4)
'(X L I J S B)
> (caesar '(X L I J S B) 22)
'(T H E F O X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `message` is not composed by chars. It is a list of symbols. Test this:

```
(char? (car '(T H E F O X)))
#f
(symbol? (car '(T H E F O X)))
#t
```

First, you would need to make a list of chars:

```
(char? (car '(#\a #\b)))
#t
```

Your other problem is syntax. You can't write `->char` like this. Also, you have an extra pair of parens.
You are trying to apply the number that results from the sum of `char->integer` and k.

```
(display ((+ (char->integer (car message)) k))->char)
```

This would be a working version:

```
(display (integer->char (+ (char->integer (car message)) k)))
```

Comment: Could use `symbol->string` for the conversion.

Comment: I didn't find a way of turning a string into an integer. something like `string->integer`

Comment: If the string is only 1 character long, can use `string-ref` to get the char and then `char->integer`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a string of your message list using `symbol->string` and `string-append`.
2. Run whatever encryption algorithm you need on the message string to get the encrypted version.
3. Use `string-ref` and `string->symbol` to get your result as a list.